# Angular View not updated after data is back from observable

Tags: angularjs, typescript, rxjs, observable

In a `AngularJS 1.6` application, inside a component, I call a subscribe to an observable and, once the data is received, I initialize an object to be used in the template. The template is a simple table.

The call to the backend API and the initialization of the local object are done correctly, as I could check with logs. However the view does not refresh by itself, when the data gets available. 
Only if I click with the mouse on the template the view reflects the data correctly.

**Template**

```
<table class="table light-gray table-no-borders table-condensed">
 <tr>
    <td>
        <span>{{maCtrl.userDetails.lastname}}</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span>{{maCtrl.userDetails.firstname}}</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    ....
 </tr>
</table>
```

**Controller**

```
export class MADetailsController {

public uid: string;
public userDetails: MADetails;

constructor(private currentUserService: IUserService, private maService: MAService) { }

$onInit() {
    if (this.uid) {
        this.currentUserService.getCurrentUser()
            .subscribe(u => {
                this.maService.getPersonDetailsFromSnapshotByUId(this.uid)
                    .then((res: QueryResult<any>) => {

                        let employee = res.data;
                        this.userDetails = new MADetails();

                        this.userDetails.firstname = employee.firstname;
                        this.userDetails.lastname = employee.lastname;

                        //Further initialization...

                    })
            })
    }
  }
}
```

**Component**

```
export class MaDetailsComponent{
static get instance(): IComponentOptions {
    return {
        bindings: {
            uid: "<",
        },
        templateUrl: "./details.html",
        controller: MADetailsController,
        controllerAs: "maCtrl"
    };
  }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Angular doesn't know about data change.  Im not sure if RxJS triggers digest cycle

> Only if I click with the mouse on the template the view reflects the
>   data correctly.

By click you triggered digest cycle and this is a reason why it worked.

You can call digest cycle just by wrap data with `$timeout` as:

```
$timeout(() => {       
    let employee = res.data;
    this.userDetails = new MADetails();

    this.userDetails.firstname = employee.firstname;
    this.userDetails.lastname = employee.lastname;
}, 0);
```

---

Hope it will help

Comment: many thanks for the answer. Indeed now it show correctly. I thought AngularJS was still able to "actively listen" to observables changes.

Comment: @Luca I hope you can find some wrapper plugin for RXJS

Comment: Wouldn't `$scope.$applyAsync(fn)` be more appropriate?